# How to make one component take as little space as possible with two side-by-side components?

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel, layout-manager

I am trying to accomplish the following:

1. A footer at the bottom of a JFrame, with two components: a JLabel on the left and a panel with three buttons inside of it on the right
2. I want for the right-side buttons panel to take up as little space as possible meanwhile the JLabel fills up the width of the hosting JFrame minus the width of the buttons panel.
3. The JLabel has a bevel border around it, the Buttons do not
4. The Buttons have next to no space between them

I have been testing aroun with various Swing layouts to get this working, but no luck so far. Currently I'm trying GridBagConstraints after following a tutorial; here is what it looks like now:
[image]

As you can see it's not working and I don't know why.

And here is my current code:

```
public class MessageFooter extends JPanel {

  private static final int BORDER_WIDTH = 5;

  private final JLabel _recentMessage = new JLabel();

  private int _footerHeight;

  /*package*/ MessageFooter() {

    // Set the size of the footer
    _footerHeight = FlowFramePrefs.getUserPrefFontSize() + (BORDER_WIDTH * 2);

    this.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);

    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

    this.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(java.lang.Integer.MAX_VALUE, _footerHeight));
    this.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(0, _footerHeight));
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(_footerHeight, _footerHeight));
    this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

    // JLabel
    JPanel labelPanel = new JPanel();
    _recentMessage.setText("   Blahhhhh");
    labelPanel.add(_recentMessage);//, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    labelPanel.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED));
    //_recentMessage.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);

    // Buttons
    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
    //buttonPanel.setAlignmentX(Component.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);
    // Create the buttons
    JButton upprB = new JButton("U");
    upprB.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
    upprB.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
    JButton downB = new JButton("D");
    downB.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
    downB.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
    JButton openB = new JButton("O");
    openB.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
    openB.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
    buttonPanel.add(upprB);
    buttonPanel.add(downB);
    buttonPanel.add(openB);

    // Add both
    c.weightx = 1.0;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    this.add(labelPanel, c);
    c.weightx = 0.0;
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 0;
    this.add(buttonPanel, c);
  }

 ...

}
```

Comment: Are you using some IDE like Netbeans?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "footer" panel should be a `BorderLayout`.

Then you create a "buttons" panel and add the buttons to that panel. Then this panel would be added to the "BorderLayout.LINE_END" of the footer panel. This means the buttons will all be displayed at their preferred size.

Then you add the label to the "BorderLayout.CENTER" of the footer panel. The label will now occupy all the available remaining space.

Something like:

```
JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
buttons.add(button1);
...

JPanel footer = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
footer.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
footer.add(buttons, BorderLayout.LINE_END);

frame.add(footer, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on @camickr 's answer I created an example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;

public class MessageFooter extends JFrame {

    public MessageFooter() {

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel footer = new JPanel();
        footer.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));

        JPanel labelPanel = new JPanel();
        labelPanel.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED));

        JButton u = new JButton("U");
        u.setMargin(new Insets(0,0,0,0));

        JButton d = new JButton("D");
        d.setMargin(new Insets(0,0,0,0));

        JButton o = new JButton("O");
        o.setMargin(new Insets(0,0,0,0));

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Sample Text");

        buttonPanel.add(u);
        buttonPanel.add(d);
        buttonPanel.add(o);
        labelPanel.add(label);
        footer.add(labelPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        footer.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);

        add(footer, BorderLayout.SOUTH);    
        setSize(500,500);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MessageFooter();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful

Answer (score -1):

Try using absolute layout i.e `this.setLayout(null)` now you can give specified amount space to each of the components you are using.

Supposing that the `MessageFooter` is of Dimensions - 1000(width), 50(height)

Now that the layout of `MessageFooter` is null, we can set the positions of the buttons or as well as the `buttonPanel`

```
this.setLayout(null);
this.setSize(new Dimension(1000,50));
labelPanel.setBounds(0,0,800,50);
buttonPanel.setBounds(800,0,200,50);
```

for further details you can go through this [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html)

Comment: (1-) Never a good solution. The layout managers can position the components at an exact location that will take into consider the preferred size of the components. The sizes you use in the setBounds() methods are just random guesses and have no actual meaning.

Comment: why is it not a good solution? @@LuxxMiner I find it very helpful when I have to make customizations unlike in generic cases where in I can directly use one of the Layout Managers.